# How to define Singleton pattern with parameter using static keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, singleton, export

According to second answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015088/javascript-define-singleton-with-arguments-as-a-module), I'm trying to create `Singleton` pattern in JS for storing data and invoking its prototypes from the other instances.

A main problem is `Singleton` doesn't store the data after receives the first instance.

> [{…}]
>   0: {firstName: "John", lastName: "Grand"}

This is how I've done:

```
export default class Terminal {
    static cache(output) {
        // Singleton
        if (!Terminal.instance) {
            Terminal.instance = new Terminal(output);
        }
        return Terminal.instance;
    }
    constructor(output) {
        // Create an array
        this.logs = [];

        // Switch to an object
        const data = Object.assign({}, output);

        // Add the object to the array
        this.logs.push(data);

        // Inspect
        console.log(this.logs);
    }
}

// instance 1
import Terminal from './terminal.js';
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, input) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        // Assign the Singleton
        this.input = input || Terminal.cache(this);
    }
}
let player1 = new Person('John', 'Grand');

// instance 2
import Terminal from './terminal.js';
class Grocery {
    constructor(name, stock, input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stock = stock;

        // Assign the Singleton
        this.input = input || Terminal.cache(this);
    }
}
let shop1 = new Grocery('Apple', 12);
```

I want to let the `new` keyword inside of the class when I define the `Singleton` pattern.

Any tips to accomplish my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cache()` method needs to push `output` onto the `logs` array when the object already exists.

```
    static cache(output) {
        // Singleton
        if (!Terminal.instance) {
            Terminal.instance = new Terminal(output);
        } else {
            Terminal.instance.logs.push(Object.assign({}, output));
        }
        return Terminal.instance;
    }
```